# Right expression for combining "is" and "contrast with"?

Tags: prepositions, syntax

> "Competition **is contrast with** cooperation."

I wonder if the above sentence is right.

I think that "Competition **is in contrast with** cooperation" is right.

Which one is right?

Comment: One might say (in some contexts) "Competition is **contrasted** with cooperation."  But otherwise the "in" is needed.

Comment: Confusion between _Competition contrasts with cooperation_ and _Competition is contrasted with cooperation_, both grammatical. In the first sentence, _contrasts_ is a tensed verb and needs no auxiliary; in the second, the passive construction requires auxiliary _is_ and the past participle _contrasted_.

Answer (score 1):

*Contrast* can be a noun, so it can work as an object of a preposition, such as in the phrase *in contrast with*.

*Contrast* of course is a regular verb, and a past participle X of a verb can be used as a shortcut to express *that has/have been X* - for example, "the contrasted viewpoints" = "the viewpoints that have been contrasted."

Now, it's possible for *contrast* to take an object ...

> I heard what she said before.  Her current argument contrasts this.

and it is possible for it to be followed directly by a prepositional phrase.

> Her current argument contrasts with what she said earlier.

But saying *X is/are contrast with Y* doesn't work - beYou must say *X is in contrast with Y*.  *Contrast* doesn't really work as a modifier.